# BPy add Path in Textfile from Text-Editor

Tags: python, export, path, text-editor

.hi guys i have a problem by set a path in text line.

I put in a picture, maybe you understand what I mean.
[image: path missing by generating]

i don't know how to implement the code in such a way that the path is included in the text line **(see yellow arrows)**

and btw. here is my code from the function:

```
import bpy

myPath = bpy.path.abspath('GameName\Character\Johnny') #path from "Johnny" 

#character list with hardcoded Animations, Speed, Name etc. without correct 
#path from character
Text = '''
DIRECTORY: \Animation\Torso\Idle_Stand\\
ANIM_NAME: Idle_Stand
ANIM_SPEED: 1.00
FRAME_FILES: Frame01.obj

DIRECTORY: \Animation\Torso\Spot1\\
ANIM_NAME: Spot_01
ANIM_SPEED: 12.50
FRAME_FILES: Frame01.obj, Frame02.obj, Frame03.obj, Frame04.obj

DIRECTORY: \Animation\Legs\Run\\
ANIM_NAME: Run
ANIM_SPEED: 3.135
FRAME_FILES: Frame01.obj, Frame02.obj, Frame03.obj
'''

t = Text

#checks if this textfile name exists
if "JohnnyAnimDoc" not in bpy.data.texts:
    bpy.data.texts.new("JohnnyAnimDoc")
#add "Text" in the textfile
txt = bpy.data.texts['JohnnyAnimDoc']
txt.from_string(t)
txt.current_line_index = 0
```

I hope there's an answer to my problem.

best regards -DevilSam :)

Comment: Slosh or backslash `\ ` is an "escape character" where the char after defines what it represents newline `\n` tab `\t` etc.  Need to either escape the slosh, by using two `"\\path\\path"` or `path = r"\path\path"`  Also most path utils will recognize slash `"/" ` as  the path separator.

Comment: Slosh is also used as the python statement continued on next line, if last non whitespace char, hence the double sloshes on EOL's in your text.

Comment: ah ok thanks for the info batFINGER. but i still don't know exactly how to do this right :/

Comment: `DIRECTORY: \\Animation\\Torso\\Spot1` with the two on the end.  They are even a nuisance in markdown lol.

Comment: ah ok, but you don't happen to know how i get the "path" from "myPath" into the text line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Couple of ways.**

*Already pointed out hassle re slosh in [comments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127991/bpy-add-path-in-textfile-from-text-editor/127995#comment221540_127991)*

To include a string in another block string, could use formatting, I like the old and deprecatious `%` Checkout the python docs for string formatting `str.format(...)`

```
text = '''
%s blah 
%s blah
%s blah
''' % (("XXX",) * 3) # all 3 occurences
print(text)
```

output

```
XXX blah 
XXX blah
XXX blah
```

or use a unique TOKEN and replace

```
print(text.replace("XXX", "YYY"))
```

output

```
YYY blah 
YYY blah
YYY blah
```

Since the parts are paths strongly recommend you lookup in python docs , `os.path.join(...)`.

Comment: thank you very much batFINGER for the nice example :]